# Can I skip numerical analysis altogether and jump to other courses

Tags: real-analysis, probability, discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, coding-theory

So the situation is I have completed Single and multivariate calculus, linear algebra, differential equations and and Real analysis. Now I'm thinking about skipping numerical analysis as it's of no use to my area of study which particularly programming and coding. My prof. told me that you should skip numerical analysis and jump to probability, statistics and discrete mathematics courses. 
Now I want to know that is it mandatory to learn numerical analysis in order to do well in probability statistics, discrete mathematics, linear programming and mathematical modelling. 
I mean is numerical analysis a prequisite to learn other courses well. 
Also throw some light on how important it is for a coder to learn numerical analysis.

Comment: I'd bet you could skip it for now and just learn parts of it later as the need arises.

Comment: not necessary for probability statistics, and discrete mathematics. Depend on who teaches mathematical modelling, you might need numerical analysis. If you want to be coder, there are coders who just do Graphical User Interface. No deep math is needed.

Comment: I think it's more important to learn probability/statistics/algorithms rather than go in depth of numerical analysis - which you can pick up on your own (if really needed) or use ready-to-use packages. There are no such packages for conceptual understanding.

Comment: I've found numerical analysis to have been one of my most valuable courses throughout my career: it helped me to learn to think about algorithm design, and by understanding how numerical errors can accumulate,  I'm better able to minimize them consistent with requirements. Having supervised many coders/programmers over the years, I've seen many engineers that lacked insight into numerical processes, even though they were otherwise good programmers, and understood the math.  Looking stuff up in a book is not a substitute for understanding!   Of course, it all depends on your career.

Comment: As has been said, it depends on what kind of coder you're aiming to be. Anyway, I'd say that having the basic of numerical method would be a good step into understanding how/when can a program go wrong (specifically those programs that require heavy calculation).

Comment: @PeterDiehr suppose if I'm constrained by time as of now. I'm a maths major student and will be doing programming in my Post graduate course. So I'm saying if I want to get A's in the above mentioned courses can I do it without studying numerical analysis well. First of all my priority is finishing my maths major with all A's in them. I just wanted to know whether or not can I get good scores in those courses without doing numerical analysis.

Comment: Numerical analysis is a stand-alone course and not a prerequisite for anything else. You can pick up whatever basics you need on the go and few need to go deep into the details of numerical calculations in their work. You won't be hampered at all in probability/statistics/algorithms without knowledge of numerical analysis. As I said, with the spread of ready-to-use packages, only those who do in house large-scale computations/modeling need such a course. The rest can pick up the deeds (which can change as languages/architecture changes) on the go.

Comment: I don't think the tag "coding-theory" means what you think :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should strongly consider doing what your adviser
recommends. Presumably he/she knows something about you and
about the contents and quality of the numerical analysis course
in your department.

Having said that, I agree with the Comments of @PeterDiehr and
@BigbearZaa that
numerical analysis is crucial background to many kinds of
programming. I hope circumstances will arise later in which
you take a numerical analysis course.

Here are some questions that should be easy for you to understand as related to your question.
Answers are among topics considered in most numerical analysis courses. (These topics from my last month doing statistical
computations.)

1) Digital computers do not deal with the real numbers, but instead
with a carefully-chosen subset of the rationals that is very large,
but finite. Usually, the computations on that subset of the rationals
are satisfactory. But there are occasional rude surprises when
they are not satisfactory. Do you know what sort of surprises
to guard against?

2) There are good reasons why many computer packages define $0^0 = 1$ instead of 'undefined'. For example, in R the expression `0^0` returns `1`.  Why is that?

3) If $M$ is a $10 \times 10$ invertible matrix, under what circumstances can you trust the computed inverse to be correct?

4) You are evaluating whether a particular commercial software package
gives sufficiently accurate results for the current work of your group.
What benchmark tests should you use in your evaluation?